# Browser closes even after using detach in selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, browser, automation

My problem
I have used detach method to stop the browser to close automatically after the code run.
Its not working. Below I have given the code for your reference. Please help me.
i have tried implicit wait also but its not working
thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
"""
The browser will be started.
"""
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
browser.maximize_window()
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
browser.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com")
print(browser.title)
browser.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
print(browser.title)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/app-root[1]/form-comp[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").send_keys("OVM")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/app-root[1]/form-comp[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/input[1]").send_keys("ovm@gmail.com")
browser.find_element(By.ID,"exampleInputPassword1").send_keys("123456789")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='exampleCheck1']").click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//select[@id='exampleFormControlSelect1']").click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='inlineRadio2']").click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/app-root[1]/form-comp[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[7]/input[1]").send_keys("01/01/2000")
browser.implicitly_wait(20000)
```

Result:-

```
Rahul Shetty Academy
ProtoCommerce

Process finished with exit code 0
```

the browser closes automatically. I did not give any comment to close the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not set the `detach` option correctly. The following code works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
"""
The browser will be started.
"""
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com")
print(browser.title)
browser.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
print(browser.title)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/app-root[1]/form-comp[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").send_keys("OVM")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/app-root[1]/form-comp[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/input[1]").send_keys("ovm@gmail.com")
browser.find_element(By.ID,"exampleInputPassword1").send_keys("123456789")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='exampleCheck1']").click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//select[@id='exampleFormControlSelect1']").click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='inlineRadio2']").click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/app-root[1]/form-comp[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[7]/input[1]").send_keys("01/01/2000")
browser.implicitly_wait(20000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Its working
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
This is the thing which I need to update. I changed the code and its working fine now.